# Ionic 3: How to show Interstitial Ad via AdMob based on 10 button clicks

Tags: angular, ionic3, cordova-admob

I need some assistance. So I have successfully added Admob free to my ionic 3 app. using this plugin : https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free.

I got the interstitial ad to show but once the app has ran for the first time. I don't think this is user friendly so I would like to add a function that will display the ad every 10 button clicks. I would like this to count any button clicks throughout the app not just a specific page. I don't know where would be the best place to implement the function.

I have tried searching for various ways to implement this but most articles are about adding it in android or ios. I also used ionic 1 articles and tried to hack it make it work for ionic 3 but i had no luck. I also searched on here but have not found any working solutions.
Cant anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a provider and declare a variable which has type int and value 0 initially.
2. create a function which increments the declared variable when called.
3. Inside the function which increments the variable count, you can have a condition something like this,

   ```
   if (num % 10 == 0){      // checks if the input is divisible by 10 
        //call your interstitial admob function;
        //increment the variable   
   }else{
        //increment the variable
   }
   ```
4. Call this provider function wherever you have button click.

Hope that works!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Im new to ionic 3/angular4. I have tried what you suggested but I'm stuck. I created a provider called BtnCounterProvider and then Injected it in the app.module.ts. In the BtnCounterProvider I created a var and a function as you stated. I added the function the the btn click on the home page. When i run the add and click the btn. It crashed my app and gives me an error of  : TypeError: _co.btnClicked is not a function. What have I done wrong? Here are Images of my code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F5H4sGmvyyCmXgBaeGF7n2-Z4jLvUorH?usp=sharing

Comment: The error says it all. You have no function like btnClicked in your HomePage. 1. Import the provider in your home page 2. Inject your provider like how you injected AdMob in home page. 3. Call the provider function from the function btnClicked()